# Laravel 8.74.0 Fresh Site Displaying 500 Error - Only on the Server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am new to Laravel. I have installed laravel on localhost using: `composer create-project laravel/laravel news`. Then, server.php to index.php, and copied .htaccess from public to root. However, the installation is displaying laravel default welcome view, successfully.

The pain starts, when I have uploaded it to the server. At first, it's displaying following message:
**Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.2".**

I have added the following lines to the composer.json (in config):
"platform-check": false
and then `omposer dump-autoload`. By doing this, above message gone, and the page is displaying **500 Internal Server Error**.

I have tried every possible solution, still nothing working till now.

Laravel Version: 8.74.0
Server Php Version: 7.4.26

Please help me to solve this issue. If you need any other information, I will provide.

Comment: Can you provide the full error message, and your composer.json file? Laravel 8.74 requires either PHP 7.3 or 8.0, which makes me wonder if it's another dependency throwing the error.

Comment: Thanks @aynber for commenting. There is no error message is showing. However, I did  error reporting on from .env >> APP_ENV=local and APP_DEBUG=true. How to provide composer.json ?

Comment: The composer.json is a file in your project root. Just paste the contents here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is better to add a php8 version on your local than downgrading your laravel version to 7.

Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.2" - tells that your laravel require you to have have php version 8.0.2 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing a lower version of laravel. For example:

composer create-project laravel/laravel=8.0.* news

Comment: Thank you @Farajayh for answering. I have tried your command. It's displaying:

  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 8.0.* in a version installable using your PHP version, PHP extensions and Composer version.

Comment: I can't remember the versioning. But you can install Laravel 7, if you don't have a problem with that. Use composer create-project laravel/laravel=7.*.* news

Comment: By the way did you try this:  composer update --ignore-platform-reqs

Comment: Thank you @Farajayh for your time. Yes I have tried this: composer update --ignore-platform-reqs. Its further not displaying "Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.2".", but displaying 500 error when I have uploaded the copy to the server.

Comment: Turn on error-reporting. It will help you pin-point the particular package that is causing issues

Comment: Did that too using APP_ENV=local and APP_DEBUG=true. Still, it's displaying 500 Internal server error. Even I have tried from config/app.php, 'debug' => (bool) env('APP_DEBUG', true),